# Integration Testing with Devise + Omniauth + Rspec + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, azure-active-directory, capybara, omniauth

I am trying to write some integration tests using Rspec (feature) alongside Devise and Omniauth. The OAuth provider I am using is `azure_activedirectory`.

I have followed the tutorial [here at the Omniauth wiki](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing)

I don't think I am doing it right. When I launch an integration test, the link for the login (localhost:3000/omniauth/azure_activedirectory) behaves like it would in dev or production, with the link directing the client to the omniauth portal page.

Of course given this is a test, I can't store credentials here.

It appears from the code in the wiki link that it should instead feed a login using a mock_auth.

Here is my current spec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

Capybara.app_host = "http://lvh.me"
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:azure_activedirectory, {:uid => '12345'})

RSpec.feature "AuthenticatesUser", type: :feature do

  before do 
    Rails.application.env_config["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:azure_activedirectory]
  end

  scenario "User can login", js: true do
    WebMock.allow_net_connect! 
    visit '/'
    click_link 'login'
    binding.pry
    WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true) # Re enable with local host
  end
end
```

So what am I doing wrong? I feel that I am using the example code in a very incorrect way or not understanding the process.

Or is the next step just setting up a testing oauth instance and configuring it that way to use live credentials from Azure.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**UPDATE**

This has to do with Capybara and the JS driver starting or running on a different server.

If in the interactive ruby console in the Selenium browser `OmniAuth.config.test_mode == false`. If I set it using the console in the web browser, everything 'works'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

You can not put OmniAuth into test mode in your specs. As capybara with js is in a separate thread, it has no idea about any config that was being set in the specs.

The solution was moving the declarations

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

OmniAuth.config.auth_mocks = NewAuthMock
```

into the `test.rb` environment file, that way Capybara would spawn with the correct config.